# How to store a password for later use?

Tags: outlook, passwords, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to be able to store a user's Exchange password so I can use it to perform some task later on, using EWS. I know storing passwords in plain text is a horrid crime, so what options do I have?

In my case, my application will have access to an administrative account that will have the ability to use impersonation to work with users' Calendars. I need to store the password of this admin account so I can use it while authenticating with the Exchange server at a later time. I am not planning on using the EWS Managed API.

Answer (score 2):

I have a user that created a calendar app with similar requirements.  By default, an account that has these permissions globally is horrible and not recommended.  Impersonation roles were granted by department that required access to the app to reduce risk scope.  However if you require this globally, here's what I recommended for mitigating the account/password exposure:

1. Restrict the accounts functionality to Exchange services only.  Features like log on locally and other general domain user privileges are not needed for an EWS service account that only needs mailbox access and impersonation roles.  In this case, the account cannot log onto a computer nor can it be used for RDP.  This limits exposure for malicious use.
2. The user/pass can be stored in your applications database and the connection string would also be stored outside of your application, there's a lot here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22817/how-to-encrypt-database-connection-credentials-on-a-web-server and encrypting the password within the database; further reading: http://www.darkreading.com/safely-storing-user-passwords-hashing-vs-encrypting/a/d-id/1269374
3. Restrict DB server and management access.  This is a larger issue than it should be if the database server is shared between groups.  Audit the database server access, and re-restrict if you have too many cooks in the kitchen.  The database server should also not be directly accessed by user networks but that may be a larger issue to tackle.
4. Restrict access to the application.  As in, is it available externally or only available inside your perimeter?  Either way, the application should also include authentication just to access, using Kerberos or some other SSL auth, make sure the application cannot be used to DoS the EWS services from over-access.
5. Create a one-off throttling policy on Exchange for this user and assign accordingly to prevent the application from breaking EWS or limiting regular user functionalities.  This is something Blackberry admins learned the hard way if they didn't follow recommendations.  When BES server wouldn't properly tear down connections, web services would start dropping valid client requests.  As such BES had to instruct users to create a one off throttling policy for various Exchange features.  I did the same for the user that created my EWS app.  And a few times it saved me.

Really it will boil down to good application design and coordinating requirements with the Exchange team.

Don't's:

1. Don't store the username/password in Apache/IIS pages or the connection string
2. Don't grant global permissions for the account if you don't have to
3. Don't allow unauthenticated access to the application and allow unlimited connection times

Hope this helps.